# Xcode framework Versions/Current/Headers/ error

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, mercurial

I am confused about adding a third party framework into Xcode project.

**Here are the steps:**

1) I copy the framework into project subfolder called "Frameworks". So framework is added to repository.

Everything works fine, app compiles, here is the screenshot:

[image: Everything works fine, here is the screenshot:]

2) I push the changes into repository (I use mercurial)

3) If I pull the changes on other machines or just switch between branches then project doesn't recognize this framework any more.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

The question is why it happens and how to solve this problem? I there any specific way to add a framework in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Things you add with a commit, of course, are only present in those revisions later than the one where you added it. Unless you merged that revision with the framework into another branch A, this other branch A will not know of changes made to the first branch.

Comment: What you are saying is obvious, I mean that if I switch back to correct revision or open my changes on other machine the commit is correct, all changes are there, even frameworks exists, but I doesn't work and looks weird.

Comment: Did you add the 'Headers' directory or only a symbolic link to that directory? I.e, is the directory on your primary machine (where it works) actually somewhere else on the file system instead of in your repository and you only dragged it there?

Comment: @B.S. Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today and it was because the 3rd party framework was delivered as a .zip file and symbolic links inside of the framework were lost at some point.

Here is Apple's documentation on the anatomy of a framework:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html

The document explains that multiple framework versions might exist inside of the framework bundle, so the bundle contains some symlinks pointing to the current version of some directories.

```
MyFramework.framework/
MyFramework  -> Versions/Current/MyFramework
Resources    -> Versions/Current/Resources
Versions/
    A/
        MyFramework
        Resources/
            English.lproj/
                InfoPlist.strings
            Info.plist
    B/
        MyFramework
        Resources/
            English.lproj/
                InfoPlist.strings
            Info.plist
    Current  -> B
```

The problem you have is exactly like mine. Confirm that the three symlinks that Apple documented (MyFramework, Resources, Versions/Current) are not symlinks, but are tiny files. Then delete the tiny files and replace them with symlinks to the current framework version. For example, if the current version is 'A':

```
cd NewRelicAgent.framework
rm Headers
rm NewRelicAgent
rm Versions/Current
ln -s Versions/Current Versions/A
ln -s Headers Versions/A/Headers
ln -s NewRelicAgent Versions/A/NewRelicAgent
```

If there are multiple versions in your framework, then the text in Versions/Current might contain the current version. This would be an artifact where the compression tool is storing the symlink as text instead of an actual link.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing a similar kind of issue. The result we get is the same, but the setup is different.

Posting our findings here, incase someone else finds it useful.

**Our apps high level setup**

- React Native app
- Git repo
- npm for package management (npm install)
- lots of `.xcodeproj` under one `.workspace`
- one of those `.xcodeproj` have a `.framework` that shows the issue mentioned above

**Our findings (so far)**

- it's not the actually `git checkout` thats causing this stripping out of symlinks in .framework behaviour
- it's actually how our package manager (npm) installs the said sub repo. It might be npm is doing something to strip out symlinks in install or post install phase.
- If we download or `git checkout` the said sub repo manually, framework symlinks are in tact.

**Our initial approach to fix the issue**

- Include a symlinks intact version of the framework (`Valid.framework`) in the main project.
- use `npm install` to install the packages as normal (this would strip out the symlinks in the framework `Broken.framework` file thats in the sub repo)
- have a post install script copy and/or override `Broken.framework` with `Valid.framework`
- `cp -Rf <path_to_working_framework>/Valid.framework/* node_modules/<path_to_broken_framework>/Broken.framework/`